# Clarification for the following image

Tags: probability

I can't understand the equation properly, can someone please elaborate it for me: [image: equation]

Comment: What aspect of the formula don't you understand ?

Comment: The last equation

Comment: $d/dp\,(1-1/p)=-1/p^2$, then multiply by $-p$.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of having $k$ trials is $(1-p)^{k-1}p$, so when we do the expected number of trials, we look at the weighted sum, of the probability of having $k$ trials times $k$, namely $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1}pk.$$ The next step is using the fact that the derivative of $(1-p)^k = k(1-p)^{k-1}$. Then they interchange the order of summation and differentiation. Then they use the formula for the sum of a geometric series.